# bundle exec rake db:migrate hangs on Amazon EC2 and RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rake, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance (m3.medium) that runs my Rails application and connected to an RDS instance for the MySQL database.

When running 'bundle exec rake db:migrate', the process hangs indefinitely without outputting any error. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the database.yml as:-

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
  host: abcdef.amazonaws.com
```

Run the migration as:-

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate
```

Comment: Shamsul, thanks for the answer. The configuration you suggest is exactly what I have in my database.yml as well and I also tried "bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging db:migrate" multiple times. Any thoughts on this?